Feasibility and compatibility of newer freewheels with more gears
Dimension (a company) apparently produces 5 to 9-speed freewheels. These and the Sunlite 6-speeds are the only freewheels I've seen at my LBS.
Now, I've seen warnings on this website that 8-speed (or higher, presumably) freewheels have a non-negotiable probability of causing a bent or broken axle. Additionally, some work is involved in switching from a 5-speed to a 6- or 7-speed freewheel, but they are apparently (or potentially?) compatible. My questions are:

Is it possible to switch from a 5 to an 8- or 9-speed freewheel?
If so, does one have to re-dish the wheel further/is there a higher likelihood of damaging the wheel?
Do these newer freewheels carry the same risk of axle damage, and if so do 9-speed freewheels carry an even greater risk than 8?
If the risk is there, why are 8 and 9-speed freewheels still in demand/being produced?


Great questions...
The 8, 9 and 10 freewheels are currently produced for e-bikes where the motor is in the rear hub: most of these use a screw on freewheel as the hub motor with cassette freehub is more expensive to produce and possibly patented. The axle is oversize on these so breakage is not a worry.
You could fit one to your hub to replace your 5sp block but you would need to use a longer axle & extra spacers to add space for the extra sprockets on the DS as well as probably extra on the NDS to allow the correct dish to be achieved. This means that the frame will need cold-setting(if even possible!) to at least 130mm and maybe more. A 5sp hub can be 120mm OLD or possibly less on older bikes. Somewhat newer frames since 6/7sp could be 126mm OLD.
I hope that gives you some idea.
